# How to render Object in React js

Tags: reactjs

How do I render an Object in JSX? I don't know any method to render an Object. Could you please show me an example method on how to render this data?
I want to render all data in object
Data(Object)

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { firestore } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      User: {},
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { uid } = this.props.currentUser;
    firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        this.setState({
          User: doc.data(),
        });
        console.log(this.state.User);
      })

      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container
        maxWidth="lg"
        style={{ paddingTop: "2%", paddingBottom: "2%" }}
      >
       I want to show all data on this
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Profile);
```

Comment: How did you want to display this data on UI?

Comment: @SagarPednekar yes

Comment: Things just got so much clearer

Comment: What did you want to render from your JSX code for e.g email or image?

Comment: @SagarPednekar All data

Comment: Please share your code or elaborate more on what you actually want to do.

Comment: @SouravSingh I added it

Comment: @PEEMAPODNEAMKUR Please check my code below and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display data like this.

```
  render() {
    const { User } = this.state;
    const { email, displayName } = User || {};

    return (
      <Container
        maxWidth="lg"
        style={{ paddingTop: '2%', paddingBottom: '2%' }}
      >
       <h2>{email}</h2>
       <h2>{displayName}</h2>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As the fetched User data is not an array rather is an object, User.map would not be helpful at all.

Comment: @AshishSingh Now, I modified the changes please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to render data from an object is to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

It simply means you can retrieve values from Array and Object. In this case Object.

```
let {displayName, email, lastSignInTime, photoUrl } = this.state.User;

<div class='name'>{displayName}</div>
<div class='email'>{email}</div>
<div class='last_sign_in_time'>{lastSignInTime}</div>
<div class='avatar'>
 <img src={photoUrl} alt="user avatar" />
</div>
```